# Intervals for water intake with Creatine consumption?

Tags: creatine

I am on a workout where I take a protein shake and a creatine shake (just the ingredient with a little bit of water) after my workout. It is common knowledge that while using creatine you must intake large amounts of water. Most articles say take a certain amount everyday while on it. My question is; is it important to consume water immediately after taking it, or in intervals after taking it, or does it not matter, as long as you are getting a large supply (1-2 gallons) every day?

Update: With a very high intake of water, it is equally important to increase your salt intake?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd also have a question about salt. Would you need extra salt to balance all the water out to avoid getting hyponatremia?

Comment: I will add it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on earth would you want to drink two gallons of water a day?

While the myth of 8 glasses of water a day perpetuates, you don't need near that amount of water with or without creatine. Most of the "8 glasses" came about because people's diets became deficient in fruits and veggies that are mostly water.

Now, that being said, yes, making sure that you are hydrated is good with creatine supplementation, especially when you are in a loading phase, as the creatine will act to draw water with it into the cells.

The danger with creatine is if you aren't hydrated enough is that it can lead to renal (kidney) dysfunction. You'll see this mostly in people that deliberately try to cut weight, such as boxers, wrestlers and bodybuilders. But 1-2 gallons a day is way excessive, and could lead to other complications such as water intoxication.

Just drink to thirst plus a little, make sure that your urine is clear to a light yellow and you're fine.

Comment: The idea of 1 to 2 gallons was taken from [here](http://www.topendsports.com/nutrition/hydration-water.htm). I dont think Ive actually drank a gallon in a day, ever.

Comment: The author has a criminal science degree and has lifted weights for years. Draw your own conclusions. :D   I will say that nutritionists have no real clue where the myth of 8 glasses a day comes from. An average adult sitting in a temperate climate will need about a liter a day to replace losses. (About 4 8 oz glasses, most water glasses are 12 oz or larger). Weigh yourself before and after workout, drink to replace fluids lost (You will lose some glycogen as well, which adds to weight lost), and eat healthy and you should be fine.

Comment: 2 gallons might be too much, but insufficient water intake, particularly with exercise that causes sweating has in a couple cases killed people taking creatine, so you definitely want to know what the right balance for it is.